# How to "convert" array into list?

Tags: arrays, perl

I need to use function `cartesian` from [`List::Gen`](http://search.cpan.org/~asg/List-Gen-0.974/lib/List/Gen.pm). This function requires LIST as a second parameter, but I have an array, like

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            1,
            2,
            3
          ],
          [
            'a',
            'b',
            'c'
          ],
          [
            'x'
          ]
        ];
```

How can I "convert" such array into list, so `cartesian` can be used? Putting array into list context does not seems to work in this case.

Comment: An array *is* a list, if you put it in list context.

Comment: The only time you need to differentiate between LIST and ARRAY is when you are using a function which handles arrays in a specific manner, such as `push`. Then the argument *needs* to be an array. There is no reversed incompatibility: A LIST can always be an array, but ARRAY cannot always be a list.

Comment: to summarize the comments so far: the example array you give shows a misunderstanding of perl syntax regarding parentheses vs. brackets.  So we don't know what your actual array looks like.  Show us, using your actual data and the output of `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@a;`

Comment: I am sorry for unclear question and example. I end up with the following solution: `my @b = Set::CrossProduct->new([@a])->combinations;`

Comment: If you want to ask a new a question, create a new post instead of replacing the old one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your new question, you have

```
$VAR1 = [
      [
        1,
        2,
        3
      ],
      [
        'a',
        'b',
        'c'
      ],
      [
        'x'
      ]
    ];
```

Despite your claims that it doesn't work, all you need is to evaluate the array in list context.

```
cartesian { ... } @$VAR1;
```

For example,

```
( cartesian { join '|', @_ } @$VAR1 )->say;
```

gives

```
1|a|x 1|b|x 1|c|x 2|a|x 2|b|x 2|c|x 3|a|x 3|b|x 3|c|x
```

Answer (score 6):

Parens don't create lists, they just change precedence.

```
@a = ((1, 2, 3), (7, 8, 9));
```

is the same as

```
@a = (1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9);
```

The examples of `cartesian` show a list of references to arrays

```
cartesian { $_[0] . $_[1] } [1,2,3], [7,8,9];
```

So it seems you want to create an array containing two elements, each a reference to another array.

```
@a = ( [1,2,3], [7,8,9] );
```

Then, to answer your question, evaluating `@a` in list context will return these two references.

```
cartesian { $_[0] . $_[1] } @a;
```

Comment: So is your new question "How to convert an array of 6 elements into two reference to arrays of 3 elements?"? Not enough info. Not the right place to ask.

Comment: @Ωmega `@a = ((1, 2, 3), (7, 8, 9))` is not an array of arrays. It's just an array. `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@a;` to see for yourself.

Comment: Please use `Data::Dump` or an equivalent to dump the contents of the array you want to pass to `cartesian`. If you publish the results here then we will be able to help you better.